# UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification doesn't fire off in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, background-process, uiaccessibility

I am working on a simple app where I need to make post a `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` when user is near a specific point. When the app is active, everything works fine. When I press the `Home` key, everything stops working.

To narrow down the problem, I started printing in `didUpdateHeading` (since I can't sit at my place, and have `didUpdateLocations` called). I saw that even when I locked the screen, heading is getting updated. Further, I placed a breakpoint on the line where `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` was supposed to be fired. The control arrives on that line and goes to the next line without posting the announcement.

**My question**: How do I make the `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` work in lock screen? Google maps app does the same thing. They don't use voice-over but the announcement (such as "Turn left") is heard in lock screen. Do I have to use a speech synthesizer to achieve the same? Sample code illustration would be great, as I am a beginner in iOS development.

App settings: iOS 8.2, iPhone 4S, XCode 6.2, Objective-C, App registers for location updates in background mode (in `.plist` file)

Answer (score 0):

As you commented, Google Maps does speak the announcement using VoiceOver. What you've observed appears to be a VoiceOver behavior. If you need to perform an announcement, anyway, consider using the [`AVSpeechUtterance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechUtterance_Ref/) API.

Comment: Oh, I thought Google map doesn't use Apple's Voice-over.  I am using voice-over in the rest of my app. So if I have to use `AVSpeechUtterance`, then should it be only in the background mode?

Comment: Correct. Right on both counts.